# XPath - select parent nodes based on multiple child selection

Tags: xpath

Let we have XML looks like that

```
<bookshelf>
  <cathegory name = "Programming" />
  <book name = "Tille 1" >
    <author>....</author>
  </book>
  <book name = "Tille 2" >
    <author>....</author>
    <translator></translator>
  </book>
  <book name = "Tille 3" >
    <author>....</author>
    <translator>John D.</translator> <!-- non-empty nodes are acceptred! -->
  </book>
</bookshelf>
```

How can we select **bookshelves** which have **cathegory** node with **name** attribute and at least one **book** with non-empty **translator** node?

Basic XPath tutorials do not provide so complicated examples.

Answer (score 9):

You can chain the conditions one after another:

```
//bookshelf[cathegory/@name][.//translator/text()]
```

It selects a bookshelf for which there is a cathegory child with a name attribute, and which hash a non-empty translator descendant.

Comment: Could not evaluate predicate, maybe because of limited XPath support in Python.
Thanks anyway

Comment: What about using `[cathegory/@name and .//translator/text()]`?